# How can I introduce a data based file name request to an FTP bat file process?

Tags: date, ftp, console, command

I've been tasked with updating an existing windows scheduled task. The task simply calls a windows console based FTP command using an existing script text file using the -s:ftpScript.txt syntax.

The problem is that the filename has changed and will now be based on the current date such as filename20110101.txt.

How can I get the -s:ftpScript.txt to understand that there is a dynamic filename now required? Do I have to recreated the "ftpScript.txt" file dynamically each time the task fires to then include a new static file containing the current date based filename?

Answer (score 0):

I've now since followed my initial suggestion and it works perfectly. I've posted the following below in case it helps anyone else;

```
echo Generating New FTP Request
set request=Request.txt

FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE /T') DO SET month=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=2,3 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE /T') DO SET day=%%B
FOR /F "TOKENS=3,4 DELIMS=/ " %%A IN ('DATE /T') DO SET year=%%B
set /A day=%day%-1

set yesterday=%year%%month%%day% 

set file=<filename>
(
echo open <server>
echo <pass>
echo get %file%%yesterday% %file%%yesterday%
) > %request%

ftp -i -s:%request%
```